# How to get Obligations in WSO2 balana

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

i have been working with WSO2 balana samples and i came across code to fetch advice from the XACML response .

```
StringBuilder Advice = new StringBuilder();
                List<Advice> advices = result.getAdvices();
               for(Advice advice : advices){
                   List<AttributeAssignment> assignments = advice.getAssignments();
                   for(AttributeAssignment assignment : assignments){
                       Advice.append("Advice :  " + assignment.getContent() +"\n\n");
                   }
               }
               obj1.Advice = Advice.toString();
```

In the same way i want to  fetch the obligations, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. you can do it. But here,  you need to cast your obligation result object in to relevant obligation type (XACML 2 or XACML 3). You can have some "instanceof" check there.

> ```
>             List<ObligationResult> obligations = result.getObligations();
>             for(ObligationResult obligation : obligations){
>                 if(obligation instanceof org.wso2.balana.xacml3.Obligation){
>                     List<AttributeAssignment> assignments = ((org.wso2.balana.xacml3.Obligation)obligation).getAssignments();
>                     for(AttributeAssignment assignment : assignments){
>                         System.out.println("Obligation :  " + assignment.getContent() +"\n\n");
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Asela .However ,i have no concerns with converting the string to a document and reaching particular elements to within the response object .but i have concern in iterating the attributes in the response object , when response from PDP is really big.  will it not lower the performance ?

Comment: @NaveenRayappa Can you send me the request and response format for using Obligations? in balana